# Hibernate and Lambdaj issue with grouping

Tags: java, hibernate, lambdaj

I want to perform a tree-grouping from query result set using Lambdaj. Results come from Hibernate.

I can do aggregation successfully, but then code fails on grouping:

```
List<MyClass> list = myDao.findByProperty(value);

Integer intAvg = avg(list, on(MyClass.class).getIntProperty()); //OK

Group<MyClass> group = group(list, on(MyClass.class).getGroupingStringProperty()); //FAIL
```

Exception is

```
ch.lambdaj.util.IntrospectionException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.example.entityMyClass.-2147483644()
    at ch.lambdaj.util.IntrospectionUtil.getPlainPropertyValue(IntrospectionUtil.java:61)
    at ch.lambdaj.util.IntrospectionUtil.getBooleanPropertyValue(IntrospectionUtil.java:53)
    at ch.lambdaj.util.IntrospectionUtil.getPropertyValue(IntrospectionUtil.java:45)
    at ch.lambdaj.group.StringGroupCondition.getGroupValue(StringGroupCondition.java:41)
    at ch.lambdaj.group.GroupImpl.addItem(GroupImpl.java:28)
    at ch.lambdaj.group.Groups.group(Groups.java:58)
    at ch.lambdaj.group.Groups.group(Groups.java:46)
    at ch.lambdaj.Lambda.group(Lambda.java:1237)
    at org.example.package.Class.method(Class.java:128)
    ...............
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(AjpProcessor.java:190)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.example.entityMyClass.-2147483644()
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1665)
    at ch.lambdaj.util.IntrospectionUtil.getPlainPropertyValue(IntrospectionUtil.java:59)
    ... 91 more
```

I tried to do some homework, unsuccessfully for now.

Lambdaj uses `cglib` to perform proxying. Ivy file provides a `cglib-nodep.jar` package. Our architecture project features (because of dependency with Hibernate) `cglib` standard release and `asm-all`. Please note that, due to company policy, our Ivy dependency file does not allow transitive dependency, and dependencies are decided by the dev team based on the real needs of the projects (so if Hibernate requires a certain version of `cglib`, we put that dependency into Ivy and mark everything as non-transitive).

So in **my** project I have `<dependency org="com.googlecode.lambdaj" name="lambdaj" rev="2.3.3"/>` (transitive true by default) and my architecture project, on which my project depends, has

```
    <dependency org="org.ow2.asm"                      name="asm-all"                         rev="4.0"            transitive="false"/>
    <dependency org="org.hibernate"                    name="hibernate-core"                  rev="4.1.6.Final"    transitive="false"/>
    <dependency org="org.hibernate"                    name="hibernate-ehcache"               rev="4.1.6.Final"    transitive="false"/>
    <dependency org="org.hibernate"                    name="hibernate-validator"             rev="4.3.0.Final"    transitive="false"/>
    <dependency org="org.hibernate.javax.persistence"  name="hibernate-jpa-2.0-api"           rev="1.0.1.Final"    transitive="false"/>
```

(and a lot more)

The question is: am I doing something wrong in the code? Is that an issue with Hibernate?

Comment: I asked this question originally because I thought it was a greater problem, but then I discovered I did a trivial mistake in invoking the API. Is it worth closing according to the rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trivial mistake

The API must be invoked not as

```
Group<MyClass> group = group(list, on(MyClass.class).getGroupingStringProperty());
```

but rather

```
Group<MyClass> group = group(list, by(on(MyClass.class).getGroupingStringProperty()));
```

Notice `group`...`by` syntax